# CPU percentage of a single process

Tags: process, cpu, top

How do I get the average CPU percentage (for every second) consumed by a single process since it starts until it ends (exists)? Could I make this with Top?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ps` utility for this.

To see the lifetime CPU usage percentage of a single process, you can do:

```
ps h -p $PID -o %cpu
```

To see the CPU percentage of all running processes, you can do something like:

```
ps ax -o pid,%cpu,comm
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it is to write a small Bash script that:

- takes the process/command name of interest as sole argument, `$arg1`
- extracts the PID for that process with an adequate `ps | grep` or a `ps | awk`
- keeps the PID-number in `$arg2`
- runs a cron job on the second with an executable based on a
  `ps -eo pcpu,cmd | egrep $arg1 >> logfile-$arg2`
- conditions the cron job's termination to whether the process still exists,
      (just test for the PID number you stored in `$arg2`)
- exits when the test PID does not show up anymore in the output of `ps`